# What's meaning of two colons in one Makefile rule

Tags: makefile

I know the rule syntax should be in below format:

```
targets : prerequisites
        recipe
        …
```

However, I see below snippet in [slave.mk](https://github.com/Azure/sonic-buildimage/blob/master/slave.mk).

```
$(addprefix $(DEBS_PATH)/, $(SONIC_COPY_DEBS)) : $(DEBS_PATH)/% : .platform
    $(HEADER)
    $(foreach deb,$* $($*_DERIVED_DEBS), \
        { cp $($(deb)_PATH)/$(deb) $(DEBS_PATH)/ $(LOG) || exit 1 ; } ; )
    $(FOOTER)
```

There are two ':' in the first line. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the syntax for [Static Pattern Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern):

> Static pattern rules are rules which specify multiple targets and construct the prerequisite names for each target based on the target name. They are more general than ordinary rules with multiple targets because the targets do not have to have identical prerequisites. Their prerequisites must be analogous, but not necessarily identical.
>
> Here is the syntax of a static pattern rule:
>
> ```
> targets …: target-pattern: prereq-patterns …
>     recipe
>     …
> ```
>
> The `targets` list specifies the targets that the rule applies to.